# UITableView delegate action when tableView is scrolled?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates, scroll

Is there a `UITableView` delegate-action that runs when the tableView is being scrolled?

This is probably really easy, but I can't find it.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView and table's delegate can also act as a scroll view's delegate. So you can use all methods from `UIScrollViewDelegate` for your table (implementing them in table's delegate), e.g.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

(scrollView parameter in this case will be pointer to your tableview)

Comment: Sorry for not accepting earlier, I completely forgot about this!
Thanks, though, it worked :)

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("I'm scrolling!")
}
```

Comment: `print("And my vertical offset is \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)!")`