# How to hide keyboard with animation while scrolling tableview iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, uiscrollview

I am trying to make comment section like instagram I cam check the delegate function during scrolling as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520901/uitableview-delegate-action-when-tableview-is-scrolled) 
But I am not sure how can I hold keyboard in between the states of showing and hiding. Also if anyone has any idea how to move content up when textfield start filling with data ? I have attached an screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Sort of like the Mssages app?

Comment: you have to use TextView instead of textfield for multiline comment and for handle keyboard hide/show state you can use keyboard notifications

Comment: @user2235613 got it but keyboard notifications can only help me showing and hiding keyboard and not doing it with animation like while I am scrolling the tableview is should hide only that much of keyboard part which I scrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold a reference to your `UITextField/UItextView` (btw, [here](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView) is a nice component that mimic the behaviour you described).

As you pointed out, you can then implement this method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     [self.textFieldRef resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**EDIT**

Question is a possible duplicate of [iMessage Style Receding Keyboard in an iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780753/imessage-style-receding-keyboard-in-an-ios-app) and [How to move iPhone keyboard down like in Messages.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815888/how-to-move-iphone-keyboard-down-like-in-messages-app)

Comment: Thanks you andreagiavatto, the component is great. But for scrolling, when i resign first responder it will hide the full keyboard and not the part just scrolled?

Comment: You want to animate the keyboard out of the view while still _dragging_ your tableview?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the screen shot the keyboard is slightly hidden because I took the screen shot by scrolling down table view a little. Its instagram's comment section

Comment: Ok now i understood what you meant in the first place. Anyway it seems like your question has been answered already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780753/imessage-style-receding-keyboard-in-an-ios-app) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815888/how-to-move-iphone-keyboard-down-like-in-messages-app) ;-)

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks for your help. Its really what I was looking for. Wish I could press the thumb up button more then one time. Please edit your answer and add these links form comment so it may help anyone else too in future :)

Comment: Right, glad i could help :-)