# IOS: I am trying to hide the search bar on top of my tableView until scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, searchbar

I am trying to hide my UISearchBar that I set on top of a tableView, and show when the tableView is scrolled. I cannot find the right set of codes or tutorial in Swift to do so.

Could you please help me to get this done ?
Thanks

Comment: hide searchbar by default and when scrolling make visible your searchbar use scrollbar delegates.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520901/uitableview-delegate-action-when-tableview-is-scrolled

Comment: thanks for the input. How to hide the search bar by default please ?

Comment: searchbar.hidden = YES in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you could implement your demands by writing this code:

```
    var contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
    contentOffset.y += searchDisplayController!.searchBar.frame.size.height
    tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
```

PS:you need to change variable names.

Test Successed on: xcode7 Swift 2.0 ios8.4

Comment: This one doesnt work. I implemented the code in my viewDidLoad, and nothing happened.

Comment: yes, I have a first warning telling me that  "searchDisplayController!" is deprecated. And then it crashes, with the error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: and by the way, i am using a normal search bar, not a search bar and search display controller.   Do you think perhaps I should make the switch ?

Comment: I think you need a search bar,drag it to the top of  your tableView on storyboard, then you can implement the code on viewDidLoad, i am doing a TODO app,I implemented the demand by these code,it work

Comment: thats what I did. i ll keep digging into why it doesnt.  thanks a million. i ll get back to you on this.

Comment: Sorry I am wrong ... the item you need to drag is search bar and search display controller. I check my code..is search bar and search display controller (I had a bad memory)

Comment: Hi KangKai, Ive tried it all the way, (even uncheck "adjust scroll view inset") but "contentOffset" still doesnt respond. Is there a way to initialise it perhaps? I have pasted your code and even if i change the variables, it doesnt do anything. Is there another chunk of code to add at the beginning ?    Thank you infinitely